# How to return a value in Loop and condition in each iteration?

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following function `check_overload(...)` where I check my links if they get overload or not using the parameters shown below.

```py
def check_overload(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4, step, capacity):
    iterations_array = number_iteration_tunnels(SR_path)
    load_tunnels = bandwidth_tunnel(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4)
    global overload_point
    overload_point = np.zeros(len(iterations_array))
    for i in range(len(iterations_array)):
        if load_tunnels[i] >= capacity - (iterations_array[i][1] * step):
            print "Link is overloaded"
            overload_point = load_tunnels[i] - step
            return overload_point
        else:
            print "Link is not overloaded"
            return 0
```

First of all, I calculate number of iteration for each element of `SR_path` in the function `number_iteration_tunnels(..)`. Then, using the array created by this function `iterations_array`, I do a loop to navigate that array.

I aim to return in each iteration the `overload_point` if the condition is met, otherwise, I return 0. The problem that I am facing is that using this implementation, the function returns only ones which is obvious. I could not find a way where to do it as my aim is.

Comment: If i understand correctly `yield` is keyword you want to use. Replace `return` with `yield`. Or alternative solution is to use list and return list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

- You can achieve mensioned behavior using `yield`.
- The following example try to reproduce your solution.

```
def check_overload(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4, step, capacity):
    iterations_array = number_iteration_tunnels(SR_path)
    load_tunnels = bandwidth_tunnel(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4)
    global overload_point
    overload_point = np.zeros(len(iterations_array))
    for i in range(len(iterations_array)):
        if load_tunnels[i] >= capacity - (iterations_array[i][1] * step):
            print "Link is overloaded"
            overload_point = load_tunnels[i] - step
            yield overload_point
        else:
            print "Link is not overloaded"
            yield 0

for result in check_overload(*args):
    print(result) # or do whatever you want.
```

**Solution 2**

- using list to store results.

```
def check_overload(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4, step, capacity):
    res = []
    iterations_array = number_iteration_tunnels(SR_path)
    load_tunnels = bandwidth_tunnel(SR_path, Router_1, Router_2, Router_3, Router_4)
    global overload_point
    overload_point = np.zeros(len(iterations_array))
    for i in range(len(iterations_array)):
        if load_tunnels[i] >= capacity - (iterations_array[i][1] * step):
            print "Link is overloaded"
            overload_point = load_tunnels[i] - step
            res.append(overload_point)
        else:
            print "Link is not overloaded"
            res.append(0)
    return res

for result in check_overload(*args):
    print(result) # or do whatever you want.
```